# Visual Studio Community, Professional e Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio, microsoft

Eu estava pesquisando no site da microsoft sobre todas essas versões do visual studio, a fim de achar as diferenças entre elas, mas não consegui encontrar nada. A minha universidade disponibiliza o visual studio Enterprise para os alunos poderem baixar, mas não percebi nada de diferença pro visual studio Community, sera que alguém pode explicar a diferença entre os 3?

Comment: Sugiro que dê uma olhada no Visual Studio Code ( https://code.visualstudio.com ) que é a versão Open Source e Free e atualmente suporta .Net Core e outras linguagens como Java. Uma boa alternativa caso queria uma IDE mais leve e sem necessidade de licenças restritivas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui tem um quadro da própria Microsoft com as diferenças:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais detalhes no link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/pt-br/vs/compare/

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!

Comment: Lembre de aceitar a resposta, :D